# Regex remove first character of three or lesser character words in a string

Tags: php, regex

I have strings like `+a +string +of +words +with +different +lengths`

I want to use php's **preg_replace** to remove + only froms words that are 1 - 3 characters long including +.
Required output is `a +string of +words +with +different +lengths`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without capturing groups,

```
(?<= |^)\+(?=\w{1,3}\b)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/mM8fF9/12)

Your final PHP code would be,

```
<?php
$string = '+a +string +of +words +with +different +lengths';
$pattern = "~(?<= |^)\+(?=\w{1,3}\b)~";
$replacement = "";
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
?>
```

**Output:**

```
a +string of +words +with +different +lengths
```

**Explanation:**

```
(?<= |^)\+(?=\w{1,3}\b)
```

- `(?<= |^)` Positive lookbehind to look only after the starting point or space.
- `\+` A literal + sign
- `(?=\w{1,3}\b)` The characters following the `+` sign must be (1 to 3) word characters which is again followed by a boundary charaqcter.

Answer (score 0):

> remove + only froms words that are 1 - 3 characters long including +

Try below regex using capturing groups and replace with `$1`

```
\+(\b\w{1,2}\b)
```

Here is demo on [regex101](http://regex101.com/r/dD6qP7/3)

Description:

```
\b          assert position at a word boundary 
\w{1,2}     match any word character [a-zA-Z0-9_] between 1 and 2 times
```

Pattern looks for + sign followed by 1 and 2 characters long word.

**Note:** If you are looking for only letters then use `[a-z]` instead of `\w`.

---

Sample code:

```
$re = "/\+(\b\w{1,2}\b)/";
$str = "+a +ab +string +of +words +with +different +lengths";
$subst = '$1';

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
```

output:

```
a ab +string of +words +with +different +lengths
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
$replaced = preg_replace('~\+(?=\w{1,2}\b)~', '', $yourstring);
```

**Explanation**

- `\+` match a literal `+`
- The lookahead `(?=\w{1,2}\b)` asserts that what follows are one or two word characters then a word boundary
- Replace with the empty string

The `{1,2}` is because you want to target strings of 3 chars at the most including the `+`